# io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, webdrivermanager-java

I have the following error when start tests on remote VM via Jenkins, however tests work without any issues on my local machine.

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\webdriver\geckodriver\win64\v0.26.0\geckodriver.exe
```

The tests worked correctly before and this issue started to appear from 30/04/2020/.

WebDriver manager version - 3.8.1,
geckodriverVersion - 0.26

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `forceDownload()` allows the test to download and overwrite the current driver version folder. If `geckodriver.exe` is running on (check on Task Manager), so it could not overwrite a running program.

So, before executing the test, you should check whether that program is running or not. If it is running, you must force close `geckodriver.exe`.

Otherwise, don't forget that you should quit the driver if an exception occurs.

```
if (driver) {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue.
While running from `Jenkins`, it shows the following issue. But it would pass if I run it from windows `cmd.exe`.

> io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443 [chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/34.64.4.112] failed: Read timed out
> at CsdAutomationE2E.testflows.script.JDCLOUD200618.TestStep1.beforeTest(TestStep1.java:56)